# await not working properly

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I am attempting to write a window manager for one of our programs.  It should display a series of windows to the client with each window asking for different information and then processing that information before moving to the next window.  New windows can be dynamically added or removed, thus the window manager.  In order to do this, I have a main shell that provides a parent window.  Each child window is inserted as content into the parent window.  When the next button is clicked, the child should process the on-screen info and then let the parent know that it can move to the next window.  Because the processing can take up to 30 seconds for some windows, I want to display a busy indicator while this processing is going on.  I am accomplishing that by using the Telerik RadBusyIndicator on my parent view.  In order to show the busy indicator properly, I am attempting to use await/async to call the OnNext method asynchronously.  The OnNext method is being called and the processing is taking place, but the UI thread is being locked up during processing and the busy indicator is not being shown.  The relevant parts of my code are as follows:

ShellViewModel.cs (the view model for the parent window):

```
    protected async void NextAction()
    {
                    //This is the property that is bound to the RadBusyIndicator to indicate if it should show or not
        IsBusy = true;

                    //windowManager is the class that tells the child window to start processing and provides the parent window with the next view
        bool? retVal = await windowManager.OnNext();

        if (retVal == true)
        {
            GetCurrentView();
        }
        else if (retVal == null)
        {
            SetupApp.IsRestarting = true;
            GetCurrentView();
            SetupApp.Config.RestartPoint = windowManager.CurrentViewCounter;
            File.WriteAllText("Config.xml", SetupConfig.Serialize(SetupApp.Config));
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Application.ResourceAssembly.Location);
            Application.Current.Shutdown();
        }

        IsBusy = false;
    }

    private async void GetCurrentView()
    {
        IsBusy = true;

        SetupViewInit retVal = await windowManager.InitializeView();

        if (retVal == SetupViewInit.CloseApp)
        {
            RaiseCloseRequest();
            IsBusy = false;
            return;
        }

        IsBusy = false;

        Content = windowManager.CurrentView as FrameworkElement;

        OnPropertyChanged("CanNext");
        OnPropertyChanged("CanBack");
        OnPropertyChanged("NextToolTip");

        if (windowManager.IsFinalView)
        {
            CancelText = "Close";
            SetupApp.IsComplete = true;
        }
    }
```

SetupWindowManager.cs:

```
    public async Task<bool?> OnNext()
    {
                    //calls into the current view model to begin processing
        bool? retVal = CurrentViewModel.OnNext();

        if (retVal == true)
            CurrentViewCounter++;

        return retVal;
    }

            //Called from GetCurrentView to set the current view model and perform any initialization that view model might need
    public async Task<SetupViewInit> InitializeView()
    {

        CurrentView = currentViewList[CurrentViewCounter];
        CurrentViewModel.FireNextAction += FireNextAction;
        CurrentViewModel.PropertyChanged += PropertyChanged;
        SetupViewInit retVal = CurrentViewModel.Init();

        if (retVal == SetupViewInit.NextScreen)
        {
            CurrentViewCounter++;
            retVal = await InitializeView();
        }
        else if (retVal == SetupViewInit.TypeChange)
        {
            SetupType = SetupApp.Config.SetupType;
            MachineType = SetupApp.Config.MachineType;
            GetViewList();
            retVal = await InitializeView();
        }

        return retVal;
    }
```

Again, all of the code is executing properly.  The code is just locking up the UI thread.  If it makes any difference, I'm using the Bcl compiler components with .net 4.0.  It's a big project and we're not ready to move to .net 4.5 yet.

Edit:  My response to Sethcran's answer was going to be too long for a comment.

I cant' use Task.Run because we aren't using the .Net 4.5 library yet.  However, it got me looking at Task.Factory.StartNew.  I changed my code as indicated below and ran into the problem indicated in the comment:

```
        Task.Factory.StartNew<SetupViewInit>(new Func<SetupViewInit>(async () =>
        {
            CurrentView = currentViewList[CurrentViewCounter];
            CurrentViewModel.FireNextAction += FireNextAction;
            CurrentViewModel.PropertyChanged += PropertyChanged;
            SetupViewInit retVal = CurrentViewModel.Init();

            if (retVal == SetupViewInit.NextScreen)
            {
                CurrentViewCounter++;
                retVal = await InitializeView();
            }
            else if (retVal == SetupViewInit.TypeChange)
            {
                SetupType = SetupApp.Config.SetupType;
                MachineType = SetupApp.Config.MachineType;
                GetViewList();
                retVal = await InitializeView();
            }
                            //On the following line, VS shows an "Unexpected return value" error
            return retVal;

        }));
```

So how do I get the return value from the task?

I couldn't get either of these methods to work and ended up going a completely different route.  Thanks for your suggestions, but I simply don't have time on this project to mess around with them any more.

Comment: Don't ignore the compiler warning you get informing you that `OnNext` will run synchronously. Also, avoid `async void`.

Comment: Because your task is calling an async method, be sure that your task itself returns a Task. In particular, I think Func<SetupViewInit> needs to be Func<Task<SetupViewInit>>

Answer (score 1):

The use of the await and async keywords does not, by themselves, make the code afterwards run asynchronously. By calling into an async method, it runs as normal. The only real difference is that it's result will be returned as a Task object. I suspect that in your case, since I don't explicitly see work being spun off onto another thread or otherwise queued for later, that this Task object doesn't return until your processing methods have returned, and that it is already marked as completed, and thus, your await and async keywords here are effectively doing nothing.

Considering wrapping the code you actually want to run asynchronously within a Task, via

```
return Task.Run(() => { yourLongProcessingMethodsHere });
```

This will run the code passed in asynchronously, and then return on your current thread at the same time an explicit Task object that is currently executing.

So, in short, async/await are only going to do you good on methods that were explicitely written to work with them, and that either spin off a thread of their own to do work, or else queue up an event to run at a later date, to mark the Task completion.

For more on async/await, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx

Comment: Please see my edit to the question.  I can't use Task.Run because we're not using .net 4.5 yet.

Comment: Task.Factory.StartNew as you've started using is nearly the same thing, as was the original preferred method for starting a task before Task.Run was added, so that change should be fine.

Comment: @DrewBurchett `Task.Run(someAction)` is just a shortcut of typing `Task.Factory.StartNew(someAction, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach, TaskScheduler.Default);`. [Here is a article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx) explaining it more.